# Ubuntu 14.04 root directory 100% full

Tags: ubuntu-14.04

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 .I have create a root partition of 20G despite of this it is full. I have tried almost all the stuff, cleaning and all but I don't know what is hogging my space. Please help! this is the output for    `df -Th`

```
Filesystem     Type      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev           devtmpfs  3.9G  4.0K  3.9G   1% /dev
tmpfs          tmpfs     788M  1.5M  787M   1% /run
/dev/sda6      ext4       19G   19G     0 100% /
none           tmpfs     4.0K     0  4.0K   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
none           tmpfs     5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
none           tmpfs     3.9G   42M  3.9G   2% /run/shm
none           tmpfs     100M   52K  100M   1% /run/user
/dev/sda10     ext4       86G  1.6G   80G   2% /home
/dev/sda2      vfat      256M   33M  224M  13% /boot/efi
```

Comment: I've had one service flooding its log. Did you check `/var/log`?

Comment: Can you provide details of what you've researched and tried already?  Without that, answers are likely to be suggestions of what you've already done.  Also, is SDA6 the partition?  Can you provide similar detail for the directories it contains?

Comment: 20GB is quite small today.  How do you expect us to know what is taking space on your machine if you can't find it and you're on it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [where is my disk space?](http://superuser.com/questions/489671/where-is-my-disk-space)

Comment: @fixer1234 My log is ony 12.24 MB

Comment: @JuliePelletier So should I increase the size of my root directory ? Or I should unmount Home directory?

Comment: I don't know if duplicates count across communities. There is [similar question on askubuntu](http://askubuntu.com/q/266825) with helpful answer.

Comment: @Abhimanyu:  `du -s /.* /*|sort -n` and drill down based on what you see.

Comment: There are many possible reasons for the partition being reported as full.  Without details of space usage, nobody can really help except for random suggestions.

Comment: I have removed old kernels and checked out the list of installed sofftwares. The kernel gave me 1.1 GB space but the software's space is too less to accommodate 20 GB.

Answer (score 0):

So I finally figured out the correct reason for my hard disk used up space.Actually I had orphaned docker images that were eating up my hard disk space. So I removed them with  `docker rmi < Image ID >`  to free up 12 GB of space on root. Anyways Thank you :)